# filter database using php filesystem

Tags: php, arrays, database, postgresql, filesystems

I have mission to filter database from Postgres kind and it is 57G,
i tried to using postgres PgAdmin but i'm not familiar with it , so i faced many issues like error in database syntax , out of memory and other things.

i split database for many parts using software.
but my customer requires minimum 2G.

i worked around that by making simple php script that is working on php filesystem
here is function for filter the email and username<br>

```
function extractMail($file)
{

    $input = fopen(__DIR__ . '/../sql-files/' . $file, "r");

    $output = fopen(__DIR__ . '/../output/' . $file, "w");

    $mailPattern = '/[a-z0-9_\-\+\.]+@[a-z0-9\-]+\.([a-z]{2,4})(?:\.[a-z]{2})?/i';

    $userPattern = '/[a-zA-z ]{3,}[a-zA-z ]{3,}\s/i';

   while(!feof($input)){
       preg_match_all($mailPattern, fgets($input), $mathes);
       $mails[] = $mathes[0];

       preg_match_all($userPattern, fgets($input), $mathes);
       $users[] = $mathes[0];

   }

   $data = [];
   foreach ($mails as $key) {
       foreach ($key as  $value) {
          $endMails[]=$value;
       }
   }

   foreach ($users as $key) {
    foreach ($key as  $value) {
       $endUsers[]=$value;
    }
}
    $data = $endMails;
    return $data;
}
```

and that function for put content to new file;

```
function exitFile($mails, $fileName)
{

    $myfile = fopen(__DIR__ . "/../output/" . $fileName, "w") or errorDie("Unable to open file!");

    foreach ($mails as $key) {

        fwrite($myfile, $key . "\n");
    }
    fclose($myfile);

    return $myfile;
}
```

it is worked fine for extract emails or usernames only , but when try to merge emails and usernames
by this code :

```
$data = array_fill_keys(array_values($endUsers), array_values($endMails));
```

i face problem with memory limit.
and i already changed the require variables in php.ini to make memory unlimited and executed time unlimited.

so this error back to the memory for my PC. that i cant do thing for it.

---

So , My problem now is how to merge the usernames and emails to put them in the out file.<br>
or there is away to put emails to the file then put the username beside them?
<br>
Is it possible in php or not?

Comment: Your question is highly confusing. You seem to address several topics at once. What does a memory limit have to do with a database? And what do you mean by all this "57G" and "2G"? And why is the file system involved when you use a Postgres server?

Comment: it is not several topics , all i tried to do explaining the problem from the beginning , so if there is solution to upload 57 giga (G) , to postgres database sql file, it will be great,

Comment: To me there is no connection between those aspects. Are all those aspects really relevant for the issue at hand? Why? This is _not_ clear from your description. The apparent issue is memory consumption.

Comment: but the main issue with me that when merge two arrays , that execute all the memory resources  , is there is any solution to work around this

Comment: That apparently is the issue, exactly. So the question is: 1. what _is_ your actual memory limit, 2. what is the _exact_ error message (which you did not post) and 3. what is the actual data that leads to that issue. All the rest is irrelevant here.

Comment: @arkascha , you are right , the main issue here , how to work around memory limit , with 
2 Giga file

Comment: And are you able to answer to the other questions?